# UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects cannot be read

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm trying to make use of the Blur effect but I'm getting an error reading that the the type or namespace cannot be found. Thanks in advance.
I'm new to unity so I apologize if this is an easy fix. Here is a screenshot of my code.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my code.]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;
using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Assets.SwimmingSystem.Scripts;

namespace Assets.SwimmingSystem.Scripts
{

public class Swim : MonoBehaviour
{

    private FirstPersonController _firstPersonController;

    private CharacterController _characterController;

    private Blur _blur;

    private Color _fogColorWater;

    // Default settings on start
    private float _defWalkspeed, _defJumpspeed, _defRunspeed, _defGravityMultiplier;

    private FogMode _defFogMode;

    private float _defFogDensity;

    private Color _defFogColor;

    private bool _defFogEnabled;

    private Camera _camera;

    private bool _isInWater = false;

    private float _waterSurfacePosY = 0.0f;

    public float _aboveWaterTolerance = 0.5f;

    [Range(0.5f, 3.0f)]
    public float _upDownSpeed = 1.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        _firstPersonController = GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();

        _characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        _fogColorWater = new Color(0.2f, 0.65f, 0.75f, 0.5f);

        Transform fpChar = transform.FindChild("FirstPersonCharacter");

        _blur = fpChar.GetComponent<Blur>();

        _camera = fpChar.GetComponent<Camera>();

        // Default values for FirstPersonController on start
        _defWalkspeed = WalkSpeed;
        _defRunspeed = RunSpeed;
        _defJumpspeed = JumpSpeed;
        _defGravityMultiplier = GravityMultiplier;

        _defFogMode = RenderSettings.fogMode;
        _defFogDensity = RenderSettings.fogDensity;
        _defFogColor = RenderSettings.fogColor;
        _defFogEnabled = RenderSettings.fog;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Set underwater rendering or default
        if (IsUnderwater())
        {
            SetRenderDiving();
        }
        else
        {
            SetRenderDefault();
        }

        // Handle swimming

        // 1. If camera underwater we dive
        if (_isInWater)
        {
            if (IsUnderwater())
            {
                DoDiving();
            }
            else
            {
                // we are grounded and not underwater, we might walk as well
                if (_characterController.isGrounded)
                {
                    DoWalking();
                }
                else
                {
                    // we are not grounded so we are swimming above the surface
                    HandleUpDownSwimMovement();

                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            DoWalking();
        }
    }

    // Check if we are underwater
    private bool IsUnderwater()
    {
        return _camera.gameObject.transform.position.y < (_waterSurfacePosY);
    }

    // Let's walk
    private void DoWalking()
    {
        StickToGroundForce = 10;
        WalkSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(WalkSpeed, _defWalkspeed, Time.deltaTime * 3.0f);
        RunSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(RunSpeed, _defRunspeed, Time.deltaTime * 3.0f);
        JumpSpeed = _defJumpspeed;
        GravityMultiplier = _defGravityMultiplier;
        UserHeadBob = true;
    }

    // Let's dive
    private void DoDiving()
    {
        WalkSpeed = 1.0f;
        RunSpeed = 2.0f;
        JumpSpeed = 0.0f;

        UserHeadBob = false;

        HandleUpDownSwimMovement();

    }

    private void HandleUpDownSwimMovement()
    {
        StickToGroundForce = 0.0f;

        GravityMultiplier = 0.1f;

        Vector3 mv = MoveDir;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            // go upwards
            if (_camera.gameObject.transform.position.y < _waterSurfacePosY + _aboveWaterTolerance)
            {
                mv.y = _upDownSpeed;
            }

        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            // go down
            mv.y = -_upDownSpeed;
        }

        MoveDir = mv;
    }

    // Rendering when diving
    private void SetRenderDiving()
    {
        RenderSettings.fog = true;
        RenderSettings.fogColor = _fogColorWater;
        RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.1f;
        RenderSettings.fogMode = FogMode.Exponential;
        _blur.enabled = true;
    }

    // Rendering when above water
    private void SetRenderDefault()
    {
        RenderSettings.fogColor = _defFogColor;
        RenderSettings.fogDensity = _defFogDensity;
        RenderSettings.fog = _defFogEnabled;
        RenderSettings.fogMode = _defFogMode;
        _blur.enabled = false;
    }


    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (LayerMask.LayerToName(other.gameObject.layer) == "Water")
        {
            // We enter the water... doesn't matter if we return from unserwater, we are still in the water
            _isInWater = true;

            Debug.Log("Water Trigger Enter : " + _isInWater);
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (LayerMask.LayerToName(other.gameObject.layer) == "Water" && _isInWater)
        {

            // we are leaving the water, or are we under the sureface?
            _waterSurfacePosY = other.transform.position.y;
            float fpsPosY = this.transform.position.y;
            if (fpsPosY > _waterSurfacePosY)
            {
                // ok we really left the water
                _isInWater = false;
            }

            Debug.Log("Water Trigger Exit : " + _isInWater);
        }
    }

    #region Properties by reflection

    private Vector3 MoveDir
    {
        get
        {
            return (Vector3)ReflectionUtil.GetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_MoveDir");
        }
        set
        {
            ReflectionUtil.SetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_MoveDir", value);
        }
    }


    public float WalkSpeed
    {
        get
        {
            return (float)ReflectionUtil.GetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_WalkSpeed");
        }
        set
        {
            ReflectionUtil.SetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_WalkSpeed", value);
        }
    }

    public float RunSpeed
    {
        get
        {
            return (float)ReflectionUtil.GetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_RunSpeed");
        }
        set
        {
            ReflectionUtil.SetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_RunSpeed", value);
        }
    }

    public float JumpSpeed
    {
        get
        {
            return (float)ReflectionUtil.GetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_JumpSpeed");
        }
        set
        {
            ReflectionUtil.SetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_JumpSpeed", value);
        }
    }

    public float GravityMultiplier
    {
        get
        {
            return (float)ReflectionUtil.GetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_GravityMultiplier");
        }
        set
        {
            ReflectionUtil.SetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_GravityMultiplier", value);
        }
    }

    public float StickToGroundForce
    {
        get
        {
            return (float)ReflectionUtil.GetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_StickToGroundForce");
        }
        set
        {
            ReflectionUtil.SetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_StickToGroundForce", value);
        }
    }


    public bool UserHeadBob
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)ReflectionUtil.GetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_UseHeadBob");
        }
        set
        {
            ReflectionUtil.SetFieldValue(_firstPersonController, "m_UseHeadBob", value);
        }
    }

    #endregion


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the pro version of unity to make use of ImageEffects feature.

"The Blur image effect blurs the rendered image in real-time.

As with the other image effects, this effect is only available in Unity Pro and you must have the Pro Standard Assets installed before it becomes available."

Taken from : https://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/Manual/script-BlurEffect.html

Comment: No, you don't need to use Image Effect. This was true prior to Unity 5. Right now, it is free with free version of Unity.

Comment: Ah. Sorry about that :/